# fundamental group of manifold, Lee's text topological manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, proof-explanation

I am reading Lee' text "Introduction to Topological Manifold", I have a question about his proof of theorem 7.21.  I include his proof below for reference. 
[image]

My question is about the statement underlined in red.  I know that $U$ and $U'$ are connected since they are coordinate balls but how do we know that their intersection cannot be uncountable?  I couldn't think of a proof to show that they are countable.  Any help would be great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An open set of $R^n$ does not have an uncountable family of disjoint open subsets, because it is separable.

Comment: Simpler : it contains a point with coordinates in $\bf Q^n$, so you have a injective map from the set of components to $\bf Q^n$

Comment: @Thomas, yes that's the proof that it is separable. It is reasonable to assume, though, that someone that's gotten to the point of knowing what the fundamental group of a general manifold is knows what *separable* means and how to prove that open sets hve that property...

Comment: The claim is that the intersection has at most countably many components. Why is it enough to show that we can't write the open subset as a disjoint union of open subsets? Do we have a guarantee that its components are necessarily open? (in general, components of a space are only necessarily closed in the space, not open)

Answer (score 0):

This is because $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is second countable (and thus is any its open subset $S$). In particular, every open cover of $S$ has a countable subcover (this is a basic property of second countable spaces).

Connected components of $S$ form its open cover. Would there be uncountably many of them, there would be no its countable subcover. Hence any open subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ must have at most countably many connected components. Apply this to $S = U \cap U'$.